# Consume a python RPC service in JAVA

Tags: java, python, rpc, xmlrpclib

Can I be able to consume Python RPC service in Java?

Now I have a working prototype.. I wanted to get a list of all the available services in the server..

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://192.168.1.15:8010"));
client.setConfig(config);
Object[] params = new Object[0];

Object result = client.execute("hello",params);
```

Comment: `Can I be able to consume Python RPC service in Java?` - Yes. Any other questions?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: There are different RPC protocols implemented in Python. You should ask not "Python RPC service in Java" but "{PyRo|RPyC|whatever} service in Java".

Comment: Sorry guys.. I wanted to try and create a prototype.. Now i have a working prototype. I wanted to list down all the available RPCmethods on the server at the client end. How do I do that with apache XMLRPC lib...